# Excel VBA - delete recent entry after MsgBox

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling to get my Excel-VBA-code to work. I want a button to pop up after text is entered into a cell. Here, Yes leads to the row being locked and another cell being time-stamped, but I want Cancel to lead to the cell that I was entering text into being cleared of content.

I can't figure out a way to delete the recent entry. I can delete the ActiveCell, but this is not the most recent cell (say you write text in A1 and press enter, the active cell will be A2 - or if you write text and then press somewhere with the cursor, then the Active Cell will be god knows what).

I hope someone can help me with this.

Best regards

### Christian

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 2 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim Ret_type As Integer
Dim strMsg As String
Dim strTitle As String

strMsg = "Do you approve?" & vbCrLf & "Warning: This action will lock the current row."
strTitle = "Approval"

    Ret_type = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, strTitle)

Select Case Ret_type

Case 7
    MsgBox "Your input will be deleted."
    Exit Sub

Case 6
    Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value = Date + Time
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    Target.EntireRow.Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Select

End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just be `Target.Clear`?

Comment: It would indeed! I knew it'd be something simple. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim Ret_type As Integer
        Dim strMsg As String
        Dim strTitle As String
        strMsg = "Do you approve?" & vbCrLf & "Warning: This action will lock the current row."
        strTitle = "Approval"
        Ret_type = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, strTitle)
        Select Case Ret_type
            Case 7
                MsgBox "Your input will be deleted."
                Target.Clear
                Application.EnableEvents = True
                Exit Sub
            Case 6
                ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
                Target.Rows.Locked = False
                Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value = Date + Time
                'Application.EnableEvents = True
                Target.EntireRow.Locked = True
                ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"
                Application.EnableEvents = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```